# How to grok this input with logstash?

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I'm trying to grok some lines with logstash, so first I created two patterns witch   look like this :

```
AZ_LIST [1-9a-zA-Z,]+
AZ_STRING [a-zA-Z._-]+
```

and then I configured logstash to grok this input :

```
security=0 system=23 CPU=this.adresse_false Pvm=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 Vlan2=AZERT,566,2184,798,3312
```

My filter is :

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => "/patterns"

        match => [
            "message" , "security=%{NUMBER:security} system=%{NUMBER:system} CPU=%{AZ_STRING:CPU} Pvm=%{AZ_LIST:Pvm} Vlan2=%{AZ_LIST:Vlan2}"
         ]
        tag_on_failure => [ "failure_grok_exemple" ]
        break_on_match => false  
    }
}
```

But these doesn't work

Comment: One obvious problem is that AZ_LIST doesn't allow zeroes yet your Pvm value contains a number of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend for your answer, I'm morito :o you know me ;) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your pattern. Your `AZ_LIST` do not include `0`, but your logs have `0` EX: `Pvm=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`

This is my config, I can parse your log successfully.

```
filter {
        grok {
                patterns_dir => "./patterns/"
                match => [
                "message" , "security=%{NUMBER:security} system=%{NUMBER:system} CPU=%{AZ_STRING:CPU} Pvm=%{AZ_LIST:Pvm} Vlan2=%{AZ_LIST:Vlan2}"
                ]
        }
}
```

Pattern:

```
AZ_LIST [0-9a-zA-Z,]+
AZ_STRING [a-zA-Z._-]+
```